# Representing a Linear Map in a new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the linear map $\mathcal{A}:\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}-5x+9y \\ -4x+7y \end{bmatrix}$
Obviously this is represented by the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}-5 & 9 \\ -4 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$ with respect to the standard basis. I'm trying to find the matrix $B$ with respect to the basis $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Since $\mathcal{A}\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathcal{A}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, I took the matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

However, I also expect that $A$ and $B$ should be similar - in particular, that $B=P^{-1}AP$ with $P=\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$. But doing this multiplication gives me $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Which is correct?

Comment: Don't you get $B=[1,1; 0,1]$ by the first method too? Say $e_1=(3,2)^T$ and $e_2=(1,1)^T$. Then $Ae_1=e_1$ and $Ae_2=e_1+e_2$. Thus $B=[1,1;0,1]$ which matches with the one you get by using the $PAP^{-1}$ method.

Comment: Oh God, I've been doing the multiplication wrong this whole time! Thank you, I think that clears up what I was confused about.